# How do you check an array for a range in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm writing a poker program, and I can't figure out how to handle straights.

Straight: All cards in a hand of 5 cards are consecutive values.
ex. 2..6, 3..7, 4..8, 5..9, 6..T, 7..J, 8..Q, 9..K, T..A

```
cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
```

How can I check a hand, which is an array, for these combinations? Preferably I can check it to see if it's 5 in a row in the cards array.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Also not that you are missing `1..5` in your question. In normal poker the Ace is also considered as value 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit 2:** This is my absolutely final solution:

```
require 'set'
STRAIGHTS = ['A',*2..9,'T','J','Q','K','A'].each_cons(5).map(&:to_set)
  #=> [#<Set: {"A", 2, 3, 4, 5}>, #<Set: {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}>,
  #   ...#<Set: {9, "T", "J", "Q", "K"}>, #<Set: {"T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"}>]

def straight?(hand)
  STRAIGHTS.include?(hand.to_set)
end

STRAIGHTS.include?([6,3,4,5,2].to_set)
  # STRAIGHTS.include?(#<Set: {6, 3, 4, 5, 2}>)
  #=> true 

straight?([6,5,4,3,2])            #=> true 
straight?(["T","J","Q","K","A"])  #=> true 
straight?(["A","K","Q","J","T"])  #=> true
straight?([2,3,4,5,"A"])          #=> true 

straight?([6,7,8,9,"J"])          #=> false 
straight?(["J",7,8,9,"T"])        #=> false
```

**Edit 1:** @mudasobwa upset the apple cart by pointing out that `'A',2,3,4,5` is a valid straight. I believe I've fixed my answer. (I trust he's not going to tell me that `'K','A',2,3,4` is also valid.)

I would suggest the following:

```
CARDS     = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
STRAIGHTS = CARDS.each_cons(5).to_a
  #=>[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  #   [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9, "T"], [7, 8, 9, "T", "J"],
  #   [8, 9, "T", "J", "Q"], [9, "T", "J", "Q", "K"],
  #   ["T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]] 

def straight?(hand)
  (hand.map {|c| CARDS.index(c)}.sort == [0,1,2,3,12]) ||
  STRAIGHTS.include?(hand.sort {|a,b| CARDS.index(a) <=> CARDS.index(b)})
end
```

Comment: `hand.sort_by {|card| CARDS.index(card) }` seems a little nicer to me.

Comment: @Jordan, Perhaps. I didn't think of using `sort_by` until I read your solution.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just adding a superfluous `"A"` in front of `CARDS` seems to fix an issue.

Comment: I have same question. Is `'K','A',2,3,4` valid? and similarly all others till `"J", "Q", "K", "A", 2`

Comment: I suggest that if @udasobwa invites you to join his Thursday night poker group, you respectfully decline.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : What is the reason behind using `A` two times in `Edit 2`

Comment: @Gagan, that's hirolau's suggested way of including `"A",2,3,4,5` among the hands that are straights.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I like you solution very much. Only thing to complain about is naming of `CARDS` variable, as it is not really a list of card variable anymore but more of a "straight helper array".

Comment: @hirolau, you're right. I did an edit to remove `CARDS` (even though I said I was finished, but we're never really finished, are we?). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If we map each card to a value (9 is 9, "T" is 10, "J" is 11, etc.), then there are two facts that are true of all straights that we can use to solve our problem:

1. All straights have exactly five unique card values
2. The difference between the last and first cards' values is always 4

And so:

```
CARD_VALUES = {
    2 =>  2,    3 =>  3,    4 =>  4,
    5 =>  5,    6 =>  6,    7 =>  7,
    8 =>  8,    9 =>  9,  "T" => 10,
  "J" => 11,  "Q" => 12,  "K" => 13,
  "A" => 14
}

def is_straight?(hand)
  hand_sorted = hand.map {|card| CARD_VALUES[card] }
    .sort.uniq

  hand_sorted.size == 5 &&
    (hand_sorted.last - hand_sorted.first) == 4
end
```

This method (1) converts each card to its numeric value with `map`, then (2) `sort`s them, and then (3) throws out duplicates with `uniq`. To illustrate with various hands:

```
    hand |  4   A   T   A   2 |  2   2   3   3   4 |  5   6   4   8   7 |  3  6  2  8  7
---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------
 1. map  |  4  14  10  14   2 |  2   2   3   3   4 |  5   6   4   8   7 |  3  6  2  8  7
 2. sort |  2   4  10  14  14 |  2   2   3   3   4 |  4   5   6   7   8 |  2  3  6  7  8
 3. uniq |  2   4  10  14     |  2   3   4         |  4   5   6   7   8 |  2  3  6  7  8
```

### Alternatively...

I originally posted the following solution, which isn't bad, but is definitely more convoluted:

If the hand is sorted, this is easy. You can use [`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to check each possible straight.

```
CARDS = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A" ]
hand = [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]

def is_straight?(hand)
  CARDS.each_cons(5).any? do |straight|
    hand == straight
  end
end

if is_straight?(hand)
  puts "Straight!"
else
  puts "Not straight!"
end
# => Straight!
```

`each_cons(5)` returns each consecutive set of 5 items, so in the above example `hand` is first compared to `[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]`, then `[ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]`, and then `[ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]`, which is a match, so `any?` returns `true`.

Note that this is not the most efficient solution, but unless you need to check many thousands of hands per second, this is more than adequately performant.

If your hands aren't sorted yet, you'll need to do that first. The simplest way to do that is create a Hash that maps cards to a numeric value (as above) and then use `sort_by`:

```
def sort_hand(hand)
  hand.sort_by {|card| CARD_VALUES[card] }
end

hand = [ 4, "A", 2, "A", "T" ]
sort_hand(hand)
# => [ 2, 4, "T", "A", "A" ]
```

Comment: Good answer. Consider using  `hand.sort_by { |card| CARDS.index(card) }` instead of a hash.

Comment: I prefer the Hash simply because it's *O(1)* versus *O(c)* with `index`. In this case it really doesn't matter since *c = 12* (tiny!), so I guess it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: I could see worrying about efficiency with seven-card stud, but wouldn't worry about it for the various five-card games.

Answer (score 1):

Generate list of valid hands:

```
valid_hands = cards[0..8].each_with_index.map{|b,i| cards[i..i+4]}
#=> [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9, "T"], [7, 8, 9, "T", "J"], [8, 9, "T", "J", "Q"], [9, "T", "J", "Q", "K"], ["T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]]
```

Once you have the list of all valid hands, you can now check if provided hand is among [any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) of them (valid ones) or not:

```
if valid_hands.any? { |h| (h - hand).empty? } 
   puts "Valid hand"
else
   puts "Not Valid"
end
```

**UPDATE**

In-case `2, 3, 4, 5, "A"`, `2, 3, 4, "K", "A"`, `2, 3, "Q", "K", "A"`, `2, "J", "Q", "K", "A"` are also considered as valid hands, calculate them as follows:

```
valid_hands = cards.each_with_index.map { |b,i| i < 9 ? cards[i..i+4] : cards[0..i-9] + cards[i..-1] }
# => [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9, "T"], [7, 8, 9, "T", "J"], [8, 9, "T", "J", "Q"], [9, "T", "J", "Q", "K"], ["T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"], [2, "J", "Q", "K", "A"], [2, 3, "Q", "K", "A"], [2, 3, 4, "K", "A"], [2, 3, 4, 5, "A"]]
```

Comment: [`cards.each_with_index.map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)

Comment: Hmmm.  `hand = [3,4,5,"A","Q"]; hand.sort #=> ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed`. If you change the integers to strings there's still a problem: `hand.map(&:to_s).sort #=> ["3", "4", "5", "A", "Q"]`.

Comment: I like your revised answer. Best answer so far, imo.  I was thinking along those lines but though duplicates would be a problem, but of course straights don't have duplicates. Well done.

Comment: BTW, this answer is still wrong. `A2345` is a perfectly valid street hand.

Comment: @mudasobwa is a high-roller. If he says it's so, it's so. I guess we all have to start over...

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to participate, but I can’t keep silence looking at all these oversophisticated solutions around.

```
hand = [2, 5, 7, 'A', 'J'].map(&:to_s)

'23456789TJQKA' =~ hand.sort_by{|hc| '23456789TJQKA'.index(hc)}.join ||
   'A23456789TJQK' =~ hand.sort_by{|hc| 'A23456789TJQK'.index(hc)}.join
```

In a not lame hardcoded manner:

```
suit = '23456789TJQKA'

suit =~ hand.sort_by{|hc| suit.index(hc)}.join ||
   suit.rotate(-1) =~ hand.sort_by{|hc| suit.rotate(-1).index(hc)}.join
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing classes to represent a Card (and maybe Deck and Hand too). Aim for an interface like this:

```
deck = Deck.new.shuffle!
hand = Hand.new(deck.draw 5)
hand.straight?
#=>false
puts hand
8♣ 8♦ T♠ 2♦ 7♦
```

The encapsulation of functionality gives you readability and makes it easy to extend (i.e. with suits)

Here's a more simplistic version, implemented as a single Card class. I did add suits though.

```
class Card
  include Enumerable #enables sorting
  attr_accessor :value, :suit

  @values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
  @suits  = ["♣","♦","♥","♠"]

  def self.all
    @values.product(@suits).map{|c| Card.new c}
  end

  def self.straight?(cards)
    ["A", *@values].each_cons(5).include?(cards.map(&:value))
  end

  def self.flush?(cards)
    cards.map(&:suit).uniq.size == 1
  end

  def initialize(v)
    @value, @suit = *v
  end

  def <=>(other) #for sorting
    @values.index(value) <=> @values.index(other.value)
  end

  def to_s
    "#{value}#{suit}"
  end
end
```

This works as follows

```
deck = Card.all
puts deck
#=> 2♣ 2♦ 2♥ 2♠ 3♣ 3♦ 3♥ 3♠ 4♣ 4♦ 4♥ 4♠ 5♣ 5♦ 5♥ 5♠ 6♣ 6♦ 6♥ 6♠ 7♣ 7♦ 7♥ 7♠ 8♣ 8♦ 8♥ 8♠ 9♣ 9♦ 9♥ 9♠ T♣ T♦ T♥ T♠ J♣ J♦ J♥ J♠ Q♣ Q♦ Q♥ Q♠ K♣ K♦ K♥ K♠ A♣ A♦ A♥ A♠
hand = deck.sample 5
puts hand
#=> Q♥ 6♦ 2♣ T♠ Q♦
Card.straight?(hand)
#=>false
```

Answer (score 0):

## Step 0: Let's start with an empty class

```
class CardUtils
end
```

## Step 1: Store values of card in Hash

[Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html) allows fast referencing of values of a card.

```
@@card_values = {
    'A' => 1,   2  => 2,   3  => 3, 4 => 4,  5 => 5,
     6  => 6,   7  => 7,   8  => 8, 9 => 9, 'T' => 10,
    'J' => 11, 'Q' => 12, 'K' => 13
}
```

Thus, you can reference the card value simply as below.

```
@@card_values['A']
# => 1

@@card_values[8]
# => 8
```

## Step 2: Sort the hand

Apply [sort!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) method to the hand with reference to the card values.

```
def self.sort(hand)
    hand.sort {|x,y| @@card_values[x] <=> @@card_values[y]}
end
#  => ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "T", "J", "Q", "K"]
```

## Step 3: Function that tells whether two cards are consecutive

```
def self.is_consecutive(x, y)
    val_x = @@card_values[x]
    val_y = @@card_values[y]

    val_x == val_y - 1 || val_x + 13 == val_y
end
# is_consecutive('A', 2)
#  => true
# is_consecutive('K', 'A')
#  => true
# is_consecutive('A', 3)
#  => false
```

## Step 4: Check for 'straight'

It could be done with simple iteration.

```
def self.has_straight(hand)
    hand = sort(hand)

    max_consecutive_count = 0
    consecutive_count = 0

    hand.each_with_index do |curr, i|
        prev = hand[i - 1]

        if is_consecutive(prev, curr) then
            consecutive_count += 1
        else
            consecutive_count = 0
        end

        if consecutive_count > max_consecutive_count then
            max_consecutive_count = consecutive_count
        end
    end

    max_consecutive_count >= 5
end
# hand = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
# CardUtils.has_straight(hand)
#  => true
```

## Final Result

```
class CardUtils
    @@card_values = {
        'A' => 1,   2  => 2,   3  => 3, 4 => 4,  5 => 5,
         6  => 6,   7  => 7,   8  => 8, 9 => 9, 'T' => 10,
        'J' => 11, 'Q' => 12, 'K' => 13
    }

    def self.is_consecutive(x, y)
        val_x = @@card_values[x]
        val_y = @@card_values[y]

        val_x == val_y - 1 || val_x + 13 == val_y
    end

    def self.sort(hand)
        hand.sort {|x,y| @@card_values[x] <=> @@card_values[y]}
    end

    def self.has_straight(hand)
        hand = sort(hand)

        max_consecutive_count = 0
        consecutive_count = 0

        hand.each_with_index do |curr, i|
            prev = hand[i - 1]

            if is_consecutive(prev, curr) then
                consecutive_count += 1
            else
                consecutive_count = 0
            end

            if consecutive_count > max_consecutive_count then
                max_consecutive_count = consecutive_count
            end
        end

        max_consecutive_count >= 5
    end
end
```

Comment: Apparently you eliminated the `TJQKA` streets from a result.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks, I have added the exact implementation of the consecutive card checking.

Comment: I did not check carefully, but now you are likely including `QKA23` in the result.

Comment: @mudasobwa The second condition checks for wrap around: `val_x + 13 == val_y`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it:

```
hand  = [3,4,5,2,'A']


def is_straight(hand)

  # No need to check further if we do not have 5 unique cards.
  return false unless hand.uniq.size == 5

  # Note the A at beginning AND end to count A as 1 or 14.
  list_of_straights = 'A23456789TJQKA'.chars.each_cons(5)

  sorted_hand = hand.map(&:to_s).sort

  list_of_straights.any? do |straight| 
    straight.sort==sorted_hand
  end

end

puts is_straight(hand) #=> true
```

Alternatively if you do not like all the sorting you could exchange the last part to:

```
  hand_as_stings = hand.map(&:to_s)

  list_of_straights.any? do |straight| 
    (straight-hand_as_stings).empty?
  end
```

Comment: @mudasobwa What is your point? Later in the code the we do `straight.sort` and it will sort it the same way.

Comment: Oups. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Do you need to check that `hand.uiq.size==5`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It will not change the outcome of the algorithm no, but since most hands will not be straights, doing and easy check in the beginning will save a lot of computation. That being said, I am probably guilty of premature optimization here.